# How to account for the height of a navbar when using a smooth scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a smooth scroll function that is used to scroll to specific sections of my page when links are clicked on. However, when it automatically scrolls to a section, it does not account for the height of my fixed navbar, which ends up covering up some of the content. I would like to calculate the height of the navbar and subtract it from the scroll position within my current function

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not(.carousel-control)').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
  }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the height of your navbar to `scrollTop: target.offset().top`. This is an integer value, and can be calculated by simply referencing the `.height()` of the navbar DOM element itself.

Here's an example assuming a navbar with the class of `navbar`:

```
scrollTop: target.offset().top + $('.navbar').height()
```

Hope this helps! :)